# Sharing Object Between OSGi Bundles

Tags: java, spring, jetty, osgi, apache-karaf

I have two `OSGi` bundles deployed in `Apache Karaf`. `A` and `B`. My `A` `OSGi` bundle works as basic authentication handler. I have set up my security handler it works fine:

```
<bean id="securityHandler" class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.ConstraintSecurityHandler">
    <property name="authenticator">
        <bean class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.authentication.BasicAuthenticator"/>
    </property>
    <property name="constraintMappings">
        <list>
            <ref bean="constraintMapping"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="loginService" ref="loginService"/>
    <property name="strict" value="false"/>
    <property name="identityService" ref="identityService"/>
</bean>
```

This handler is in bundle `A`. What I need to do is to make this handler as an `OSGi` service to be used by other bundles, in this case, by bundle `B`. I can not implement any interface to `ConstraintSecurityHandler` class because it is from `org.eclipse.jetty.security` package.

I have tried to create my own Handler class then extend `ConstraintSecurityHandler` and implement my interface. So `OSGi` service looked like this:

```
<osgi:service ref="securityHandler" interface="my.company.MyInterface"  />
```

This does not work, I get the exception:

```
org.apache.camel.RuntimeCamelException: org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1: Route[[From[jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8019/TARGETjobs/Indeed?hand... because of Failed to resolve endpoint: jetty://http://0.0.0.0:8019/TARGETjobs/Indeed?handlers=securityHandler&matchOnUriPrefix=true due to: null
```

So the question is how can I make this `securityHandler` bean as an `OSGi` service available to other `OSGi` bundles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution my self. I the `A` bundle I have created:

```
public class BasicAuthSecurityHandler implements Handler {

    private ConstraintSecurityHandler securityHandler;

    @Override
    public ConstraintSecurityHandler getSecurityHandler() {
        return securityHandler;
    }

    public void setSecurityHandler(ConstraintSecurityHandler securityHandler) {
        this.securityHandler = securityHandler;
    }        

}
```

And an interface:

```
public interface Handler {

    ConstraintSecurityHandler getSecurityHandler();

}
```

In my `A` bundle `Spring` context I set the security handler to this bean and made `OSGi` service from this bean:

```
<bean id="basicAuthSecurityHandler" class="com.groupgti.handler.authentication.basic.BasicAuthSecurityHandler">
    <property name="securityHandler" ref="securityHandler"/>
</bean>

<osgi:service ref="basicAuthSecurityHandler" interface="com.groupgti.handler.authentication.basic.Handler"/>
```

Now in my bundle `B` I can easily retrieve my security handler like this:

```
<osgi:reference id="basicAuthSecurityHandler" interface="com.groupgti.handler.authentication.basic.Handler"/>
<bean id="securityHandler" factory-bean="basicAuthSecurityHandler" factory-method="getSecurityHandler"/>
```

And everything works fine.